# Include() is not working as LEFT JOIN (Entity Framework 6)

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, left-join

Thank you in advance for your help.
I'm a little confused about a situation that occurred to me when using the `include()` method **Entity Framework 6**.
As I understand it, the include method works as `LEFT JOIN` when the enclosed object is `NULL` and as `OUTER JOIN` when the object has match.

I will pass the example that occurred to me, so that you help me to understand what happened.

I have the following models to my tables:

```
public class Booking
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID{ get; set; }

        public string Description{ get; set; }

        public decimal Amount{ get; set; }

        public decimal AmoutPaid{ get; set; }

        public DateTime? Checkin { get; set; }

        public DateTime? Checkout { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("SourceBooking ")]
        public int SourceBookingId { get; set; }

        public SourceBooking SourceBooking { get; set; }
    }





public class SourceBooking
{
    [Key]
    public int ID{ get; set; }

    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public decimal CommissionFee{ get; set; }
}
```

Below is the `DbContext`:

```
 public class BookingContext:DbContext
{
    public BookingContext():base("bookingConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Booking> Bookings{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<SourceBooking>().ToTable("sourcebookings", "public");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>().ToTable("bookings", "public");

    }
}
```

The situation that is not clear has occurred in the use of the following block of code:

```
var db = new BookingContext ();

var bookings = db.Bookings.Include (b => b.SourceBooking);
```

I tended because in the results the records did not come whose `SourceBooking` is `NULL`, in which case a `LEFT JOIN` would be made.

Could someone explain this to me, and give me a possible solution to this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: in your booking class you should put `[ForeignKey("SourceBookingId ")]` above SourceBooking property

Comment: Okay, but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: how can I make this same relationship using Fluent API?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

EF generates `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for *optional* relationships and `INNER JOIN` for *required* relationships.

By using non nullable `int` type here

```
public int SourceBookingId { get; set; }
```

you are telling EF that the relationship is *required*, i.e. the column value cannot be `NULL` and there must be always a matching record in `SourceBooking` table. Hence it generates `INNER JOIN`.

if that's not the case, simply change the FK property type to nullable

```
public int? SourceBookingId { get; set; }
```

Comment: makes sense to me, I'll test

Comment: Thank you. The concept was clearer to me, and it worked perfectly too.