# Entity Framework generating Inner Join with Include

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have a model which represents email with email attachments and email headers. The email attachments and the email headers both have EmailId as foreign key and both foreign keys cannot be null. I try to load the Emails model using entity framework and I try to load the attachments and the headers using include.

```
context.Emails.Include(x => x.EmailAttachments).Include(x => x.EmailHeaders)
```

Generates left outer join for email attachments and inner join for email headers.

```
context.Emails.Include(x => x.EmailHeaders).Include(x => x.EmailAttachments)
```

Whereas the above code generates left outer join for email headers and inner join for email attachments.

Is there a way to make both the includes to generate left outer join?

EDIT: Adding Model Structure

```
public class Email
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
}

public class EmailAttachment
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long EmailId { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}

public partial class EmailHeader
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long EmailId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: may you share models structure?

Comment: This most likely has to do with your model definition, see replies in https://stackoverflow.com/q/4290802/728795

Comment: Are you sure there is no `Where` condition in the query which turns the left join to inner?

Comment: please provide `Emails` class definition

Comment: İs this code first or database first models

Comment: I read somewhere that making the Foreign key nullable tells EF to use left join.

Comment: quite strange, I would look at exact generated `SQL` also if possible

Comment: Why do you want two outer joins? Look closely at the query EF generates. You really don't need a second outer join.