# How to perform INNER JOIN vs LEFT JOIN in Entity Framework Core(>2.1)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

this might be an old and on-going question for Entity Framework Core but I researched a lot and couldn't get an answer. We used to write store procedure in SQL so we will use operator like **Inner Join** and **Left Join**, recently we're rewriting everything in Entity Framework Core using C#. However, we found that no matter if we use **linq-to-sql** or **Include** operator, the sql execution behind the scene is always using the **LEFT JOIN**.

For example our store procedure will look like

```
SELECT *
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN UserRole ur on ur.Uid = u.Uid
LEFT JOIN UserGroup ug on ug.Uid = u.Uid
```

Suppose we already have a *User*,  *UserRole* and *UserGroup* class defined in Entity Framework already, how could we to perform **Inner Join  with UserRole** and **Left Join with UserGroup** at same time in Entity Framework Core here?

Things I've tried with using `Include`:

```
dbContext.Users.Inlcude(u => u.UserRoles).Include(u => u.UserGroups).ToList();
```

and using `linq-to-sql`:

```
from u in dbContext.Users 
join ur in dbContext.UserRole on u.Uid equals ur.Uid 
join ug in dbContext.UserGroup on ug.Uid = u.Uid
select new {u.Name, ur.UseRole, ug.Groupname}
```

Both above two approach is using a LEFT JOIN

So far what we can do is using *DbQuery with FromSql by plain sql*, but we don't think that's a property way of using Entity Framework. So can it be done with traditional **Include** and **linq-to-sql** ways?

Also I looked at [answer about using `WithRequired` and `WithOptional`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290802/entity-framework-include-with-left-join-is-this-possible/4299667#4299667) in table mapping relationship with FluentApi, but that's not what I want, because some of my business logic needs `INNER JOIN` between `User` and `UserRole` while other scenario may need `LEFT JOIN` between `User` and `UserRole`, so we need to write *query* or *code that EF understand* to differentiate the correct join we want.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: A useful comment [If the navigation property's key is nullable and the entity mapping uses WithOptional, then the query EF uses will use a LEFT JOIN. If navigation property's key is not nullable or the entity mapping uses WithRequired then it uses INNER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4299667/2557128). Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35349312/2557128).

Comment: Also note EF Core 2.2 has some fixes for `SelectMany` and proper join types.

Comment: @NetMage, Thank you for your information, I did check about that answer already, however the "WithRequired" and "WithOptional" are configuration between tables mapping in FluentApi(One-time), not what I could use in my specific query logic. For example, some of my business logic may need `User INNER JOIN UserRole` and some other logic may need `User LEFT JOIN UserRole`.

Comment: Hi @Ben, please see my edited approaches that I tried with using `Include` and `linq-to-sql` so far, the ef core doesn't know that it should use `INNER JOIN` with one property and `LEFT JOIN` with another property..Thank you!