# Left join using Include() in EF 6 LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-6, left-join

I am using `Include()` method in LINQ to join two tables (Student and StudentLibrary) with StudentId as foreignKey. It is working as inner join, however I need to do the left join using Include().

```
var result = dbcontext.Student
             .Include(x=> x.StudentLibrary).DefaultIfEmpty() 
             .Select(x=> Mapper.Map<StudentModel>(x))
             .ToListAsync();
```

Below is my model

```
public class StudentModel
{
     public int Id {get; set;}

     public string Name {get; set;}

     public StudentLibraryModel StudentLibraryInfo {get; set;}
}

[Table("Student")]
public class Student
{
     [key]
     public int Id {get; set;}

     public string Name {get; set;}

     [ForeignKey("StudentId")
     public StudentLibrary StudentLibraryInfo {get; set;}
}
```

The `Student` entity is mapped to `StudentModel`. The case where a student does not have StudentLibrary details, the Include() method does not return that record and act as inner join. How can I make Include() behave as left join. I tried using  DefaultIfEmpty() but its not working.

Comment: Probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290802/entity-framework-include-with-left-join-is-this-possible helps?

Comment: What happens in `Mapper.Map<StudentModel>(x)`? And which query is generated when yo only run `dbcontext.Student.Include(x=> x.StudentLibrary)`?

Comment: `Include` is (apparently) already an outer join - what happens if you leave off the `DefaultIfEmpty` (which isn't doing what you think anyway)? (Basically you are doing `dbcontext.Student.DefaultIfEmpty()` while possibly confusing EF... BTW, what is the type of the foreign key field in `Student` that matches to `StudentLibrary`?

Comment: One detail is you are missing an `await` on that `ToListAsync` call.  As for that, Selecting Student /w `.Include(x => x.StudentLibrary)` would not be triggering a INNER JOIN condition. If you are using Automapper I would also recommend using `ProjectTo` in the Linq expression rather than fetching a Student and then calling `Map`. This would negate the need for `Include` entirely and generate a more efficient query.

Answer (score 0):

The link shared by Timothy G. does have an answer.

You should set the foreign key as nullable on both the database table and the entity class.